# Efficient downsampling with core image

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

Per the *Getting the Best Performance Page*,

> Use Core Graphics or Image I/O functions to crop or downsample, such as the functions CGImageCreateWithImageInRect or CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex.

However, I'm wondering how true this is if you're working solely in Core Image for image processing. If I have an image that needs to be downsampled and then filtered, along with other things, wouldn't it be less efficient to convert to CGImage, downsample, then convert back to CIImage for other uses?

I'm wondering if it would simply be better to work in the Core Image framework if downsampling is apart of the image processing algorithm you're performing. Certainly if the above is faster I'd like to give it a try, but I'm not sure there's any other way to downsample something as fast as possible. No, unfortunately CILanczosScaleTransform is horribly slow, I wish Core Image had a faster way in built to scale images besides this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the code below, which I found here:

**http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2014/12/scaling-resizing-and-orienting-images.html**

```
extension UIImage {
    public func resizeToBoundingSquare(_ boundingSquareSideLength : CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let imgScale = self.size.width > self.size.height ? boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.width : boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.height
        let newWidth = self.size.width * imgScale
        let newHeight = self.size.height * imgScale
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return resizedImage!
    }
}
```

After downsizing things and/or making various pixel sizes consistent, I then use CI filters, both custom and chaining. I'm not seeing any performance or memory issues.

Comment: The issue here seems to be that your extension works with UIImages, which means if you're in the middle of chaining, that you have to do a conversion.

Comment: Actually, no. My app does the following sequence: Load into UIImage...downsize...create CIImage...CIFilter(1)...CIKernel(1)...CIKernel(2)...CIFilter(2)...UIImage

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have seen fastest performance by using a CGAffineTransform(scale X, y) on the CIImage itself.  I tried the CGImagesource thumbnail method and the overhead way outstripped any benefits, perhaps due to having to do more source conversions.  Note that I am starting with a CVSampleBuffer so my chain is like:

CVSampleBuffer -> CIImage -> downsample with CGAffineTransform -> CIFiltering using a filter chain... input directly to VNRequest.  I am able to get 60Hz direct-from-camera realtime processing using this method, although I would like to optimize it further which is why I am searching for an even faster option!